# Woocommerce - Cart form is being duplicated after adjusting the input quantity

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

After adjusting (increase or decrease) the quantity of the products on the cart page of my e-shop, the whole section is being duplicated. What I found on the web is that the problem si probably in the form: "woocommerce-cart-form".

I have only one customization connected with quantity and it is automatic update of cart totals after adjusting the quantity (without button). I am attaching the code below. But this is not the reason of this problem, the same will happen with the cart update using button.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {

?><script>
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    let timeout;
    $('.woocommerce').on('change', 'input.qty', function(){
        if ( timeout !== undefined ) {
            clearTimeout( timeout );
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click"); // trigger cart update
        }, 1000 ); // 1 second delay, half a second (500) seems comfortable too
    });
} );
</script><?php
} );
```

Below you can find how it looks after any quantity adjust. Good to know is that cart totals (price) are correct and if I refresh the page after this problem happen, all is correct. It is probably some bug with the cart update function.

Thank you for any hint!

**Before adjusting the quantity:**[image]

**After adjusting the quantity (this happened before woo notices appeared):[image]**

**After adjusting the quantity 2 (this happened after woocommerce notices appeared):**
[image]

Comment: Your code works in storefront theme without any item duplication (no issues)… So there is something else making trouble, It can be some other custom code, a plugin or your theme customizations. Maybe it's related to plus / minus quantity buttons script, or to something else.